# How can I put the images on the page so that they are angled. [IMG attached.]

Tags: html, css, image, styling

I want to put three images in a similar way as in the attached picture below. What tools can i use for it? Is it in principle possible to do it in HTML/CSS?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt1oJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the clip-path method to attach the pictures at an angle. Use the clip-path maker.

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Poorie Happy that he helped you. but you must click grey checkmark next to his answer. to help new people in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour, thank you. Didn't notice it.